# Combine as array of STRUCTs some columns to existing array

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this schema

[image]

I want to get one single ARRAY of STRUCTS that merges `(feature,numerical_value)` with already array of structs of `categorical_value`. Be aware that category can be empty string as well, that we want to skip.

I managed to do it this way, but I am looking for an alternative shorter way:

```
select centroid_id,array_agg(struct(name,value) order by centroid_id) as cluster from (
select centroid_id,concat(feature,'_',category) as name,value 
    FROM
    ML.CENTROIDS(MODEL `modelv1`), unnest(categorical_value)
    where length(category)>0
union all
select centroid_id,feature as name,numerical_value as value
FROM
    ML.CENTROIDS(MODEL `modelv1`)
    where numerical_value is not null
) 
group by centroid_id
order by centroid_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT centroid_id, 
  (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(name,value)) FROM (
      SELECT CONCAT(feature,'_',category) AS name,value FROM UNNEST(categorical_value)
      WHERE LENGTH(category)>0
      UNION ALL
      SELECT feature, numerical_value
    ) 
    WHERE value IS NOT NULL
  ) AS cluster
FROM
    ML.CENTROIDS(MODEL `modelv1`)
```

OR

```
#standardSQL
SELECT centroid_id, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT name,value FROM (
      SELECT CONCAT(feature,'_',category) AS name,value FROM UNNEST(categorical_value)
      WHERE LENGTH(category)>0
      UNION ALL
      SELECT feature, numerical_value
    ) 
    WHERE value IS NOT NULL
  ) AS cluster
FROM
    ML.CENTROIDS(MODEL `modelv1`)
```